# Create a function based on data set

Tags: functions, data-analysis

I have a data set:

```
x        y
70 ... -0.05
60 ... -0.0225
50 ... -0.01
45 ... +0.008
40 ... +0.015
30 ... +0.018
20 ... +0.038
15 ... +0.02
10 ... +0.01
5  ...  0
1  ... -0.02
```

How would I go about creating a function which for any $ x > 0 $ generates $y$ based on this data? (using spline interpolation, y values don't have to be exact match)

Comment: There are infinitely many functions that return those values. We need more detail.

Comment: [Spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) ?

Comment: @5xum it should be a continuos function which fills in the gaps (x,y) pairs

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA yes, exactly!

Comment: @Mykybo There are still infinitely many functions that satisfy your condition.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### On Approximating Functions or Fitting Models

#### A short essay on the topic with exercises at the bottom

Here's the situation: you have a dataset of pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ where $i$ is an indexing variable, assumed to be an integer and $0\le i\le n$ and where  $n$ is the total number of datapoints.

In math, there are two ways to define a function $g$. The first way is to write an expression for $g(x)$ and the second is to write down the set total set of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $y=g(x)$. Because the set of points for real-valued functions (functions defined on the real numbers) would be impossible to write down because there are an uncountably infinite number of such points, we prefer to define functions with the former option.

Now when we have a dataset of points, we can imagine that there is a function $F(x)$ and these points come from the set of pairs $(x,y)$ such that $y=F(x)$. However, knowing just the datapoints is useless to us if we want to know the value of the function for some $x$ not included in the data. Our challenge is to develop a method for figuring out what $F$ is.

Let's take a moment to think about how we'll solve this problem.  We need to reconstruct the rule version of the function $F$ from its datapoints.

To start, we make an informed assumption about the symbolic structure of $F$ – whether it is linear, polynomial, etc. I.e., you choose the structure of the function you think best describes the data. Some functions will be of the format $f(x)=Ce^x$, others of the form $f(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$, and yet others of the form $f(x) = m\ln x + b$.

This symbolic structure will be formally defined as a model:

**Definition 1.1**

> A **model** is a function $f$ with parameters $w_1, ..., w_n$ and independent variable $x$ declared as $$y = f(x,w_1, ..., w_n)$$

Once we have made an educated guess as to the structure of our model, we will want to find the best set of parameters to our model. We will call this endeavor "*fitting a model*"

**Definition 1.2**

> We say we are trying to **fit** a model $f$ on a set of data points of some unknown function $F$ $\{(x_i, y_i)\}$,  if our goal is to best approximate $F$ with $f$

That is, we want to know what the best parameters are so that $f$ is as close as possible to $F$. But we are still groping around in the dark because our definition of "approximate" is ambiguous

**Definition 1.3**

> We say we are trying to approximate a function $F$ with a model $f$ if we are trying to find the set of parameters $\{w\}$ to $f$ such that for any $x_i$ in our dataset the value $\hat{y_i}=f(x_i, w_1, ..., w_n) $ is as close as possible  to the actual value of the function at $x_i$ which is $F(x) = y_i$.

What do we mean by making a model "as close as possible" to a function.

We define some function which takes in the actual value of the function and our guess and spits our a number representing how bad our guess is. Let us say that this is called a distance function defined as $d(\hat{y}, y)$. Formally, it takes as input an actual value of the function at some $x$ value, $F(x)=y$ and a value of the function predicted by our model $f(x)=\hat{y}$, and spits out a number. This number will be how far  $\hat{y}$ is from $y$.

Our goal will be to find the set of parameters to our model so that we get our distance $e$ as low as possible across the entire dataset.

The most naive way to approximate $F$ is to just keep on making random guesses for the set of parameters to the model $f$. So if we have $q$ number of parameters, we just keep on find $q$ random numbers and feed them as parameters to $f$ and choose the set which minimizes

Of course this method can work on the first try, but it is exceedingly unlikely it actually will. We really need an algorithm for finding the set of parameters to our model.

It will have the following flavor:

1. Start with some set of parameters
2. Determine how much error there is with these parameters
3. Change each parameter an amount proportional to how much they contribute to the error
4. Keep on doing this until the error converges on some minimum.

### Getting Specific

Here's where we are now:

1. We have a symbolic model which we think will be a good approximator to our function
2. We need to **fit** this model by making its guesses as good as possible.

We shall say that getting our guesses to be as good as possible means finding the parameters which make $e$ as low as possible over the entire dataset. For our purposes, we will define an error function which takes the values of $D$ for all actual values of the function and predicted values of the function and spits out a number representing the error of our model. We will need to get this error as little as possible.

If we take $D$ to be defined as the square of the distance between the actual value of the function and that value predicted by our model

$$
D(\hat{y}, y) = \left(y-\hat{y}\right)^2
$$
Then we can define the  error function called $E$. We need to get the value of $E$ as low as possible. Taking
$$
E = \frac{1}{n}\sum^m_{j=0}d(\hat{y}_j, y_j)
$$
Which becomes, when we expand $D$ and remember that $\hat{y_i} = f(x_i, w_1, ..., w_n)$
$$
E=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{j=m}{ \left(y_j-\hat{y_j} \right)^2  }
$$
where $m$ is the number of data points we have for the function we are trying to approximate $F$.

Notice that keeping the data static (obviously), $E$ depends only the parameters $w_j$ just like we want it to.

This expression for error $E$ essentially says that for each datapoint, take the difference of the predicted value and the actual value, square it, sum up all such datums, and then average them to the number of datums.

Now, with everything defined, we will want to find the set of parameters $\{w_i\}$ which gets the smallest error possible, trying to get the error to zero. In other words, we want to find a set of parameters for which $E$ is at a minimum. Stated more bluntly, we want make our guesses for the output of the function on all data points closest to what it actually is.

How do we do this?

### The Secret Sauce – The Learning Rule

If we know how much each parameter $w_i$ contributes to error, we can update it accordingly. Let's say we know that the rate of change of error $E$ as $w_i$ increases is $r_i$:
$$
r_i = \text{ rate of change of error for each } w_i
$$
 Then we can change $w_i$ in the direction for which $E$ decreases.

fIf we define some $\alpha$ satisfying the constraints $0<\alpha<1$ (arbitrary but sensible restrictions on $\alpha$, you'll see why) then we can use a rule for updating each parameter based on how strongly it contributes to error:
$$
w_{i,t+1} = w_{i,t}-\alpha r_i
$$
**This is the most important equation here.**

Take a moment to think about what kind of a statement it is making. We are updating the parameter $w_i$ by an amount linearly proportional to how strongly it contributes to error. The minus sign is because $r_i$ tells us how much the error increases as $w_i$ gets larger, so we need to go in the opposite direction for error to get smaller with respect to $w_i$. Now, if $w_i$ contributes strongly to error, it will be updated much because $r_i$ will be large, and if its contribution is less  strong, it will be updated less. This is all directly implied by the update rule

(Note that the $i$'s under the parameters $w$ and rates $r$, are different that the $i's$ under the data points and model output $y_i, x_i, \hat{y}_i$. $i$ is just a general indexing variable)

### This is good and all, but you haven't told me how I can calculate how strongly each parameter effects error.

Bear with me here if you don't know calculus.

**Definition 1.3**

> Lets say we have  a function with multiple independent variables $g(v_1, ..., v_j)$. The derivative of the function $g$  with respect to a variable $v_i$ is a number representing how the value of the function $g$ changes keeping ever other variable constant and changing $v_i$.
>
> We denote the derivative with the notation $\frac{dg}{dv_i}=L$ which says the derivative of $g$ with respect to $v_i$ is some number $L$. You might also see the slightly similar notation $\frac{d}{dv_i}[g]$ used.

Think for a moment how this definition could very useful to us. In fact, it constitutes the core mathematical underpinnings of regression. Remember that we are trying to minimize the error $E$ which is a function of the parameters $w_i$. Knowing how to take the derivative of error with respect to each parameter $w_i$ is exactly what we need to find $r_i$ and thereby update each $w_i$ accordingly.

Recall that the error function $E$ takes as inputs all data values $y_i$ and $x_i$ and all parameters $w_i$ and $w_i$ is the indepdendent variable.

Then taking the derivative $\frac{dE}{dw_i}$ for each $w_i$ yields $r_i$:

$$
r_i = \frac{dE}{dw_i}
$$

Now that we know how to calculate $r_i$, let me restate the update rule 
more explicitly:

$$
w_{i,t+1} =  w_{i,t} - \alpha r_i =  w_{i,t} - \alpha \frac{dE}{dw_i}
$$

This means we will need to derive an independent learning rule for each $w_i$ which we will do in **example 1.1**

### Derivative Rules

As an integral aside (haha), here are some rules for computing derivatives which come up when we want to derive the expressions for each update . Why these rules are true is not trivial and will take many tens of pages of writing to explain fully.

Function multiplied by a constant:

> $\frac{d}{dx}\left[cg(x)\right] = c\frac{dg}{dx}$ for some constant $c$

Sum of functions

> For some function G(x) defined as the sum of individual functions $g_1(x) + g_2(x) +  ... +  g_n(x)$, it is true that 
>     $$ \frac{dG}{dx} = \frac{dg_1}{dx} +  \frac{dg_2}{dx} + ... +  \frac{dg_n}{dx} $$

Square of the difference of two functions

> For some function $G(x) = (c - g(x))^2$ for some constant $c$ and another function $g(x)$, it is true that 
>     $$\frac{dG}{dx} = 2(c-g(x))\frac{dg}{dx} $$

That is all we need.

Now, there are two important theorems in calculus that are relevant to us. The proofs are not trivial and can be searched for online if you are interested. This will require a bit of background in calculus.

**Theorem 1.1**

> A function is at a minimum if the derivative of the function is zero

**Theorem 1.2**

> All functions assume a minimum value on any interval

From these two results of calculus, we know that our error function will have a minimum and that that minimum will be when it's derivative is zero.

#### Getting into Action

**Example 1.1**

Now how does all this mumbo jumbo theory actually play out for fitting a linear function of the form $F(x)=mx + b$. All we have to begin are a set of datapoints for this function.

Well, referencing what I said in the beginning, we need to know the symbolic structure of our linear function. I have already told you that we want to fit a linear model of the form $f(x, w_1, w_2)=w_1x+w_2$. We have thus every possible linear function in the structure of  our model$f$ and need only to find the set of $w$s which best approximate our function.

Now let us take the derivative of error with respect to each $w_i$, trusting that I know how to take derivatives:

Beginning with
$$
E=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{m}{d(y_j, \hat{y}_j)}
$$
Because the $\sum$ operator is linear and derivatives just work on each member of the sum, and $1/m$ is a constant, the derivative of $E$ with respect to each term will be the sum of the constant times the derivative of each of the summation terms, from our derivative rules

Let the summation term be, replacing $\hat{y_j}$ with $\hat{y}_j = f(x_j, w_1, ..., w_n)$ 
$$
D(y_j, \hat{y}_j)=\left(y_j-w_1x_j-w_2\right)^2
$$
Then the derivative for each individual distance for each datapoint with respect to each parameter $w_i$
$$
\frac{dD}{dw_i} = 2[y_j-w_1x_j-w_2]\times \frac{d}{dw_i}(w_1x_j+w_2)\\
$$
And thus, using the derivative rules
$$
\frac{dD}{dw_1} =2[y_j-w_1x_j+w_2]w_1\\
\frac{dD}{dw_2} = 2[y_j-w_1x_j+w_2]
$$
Finally, we integrate these ideas into the error function $E$ to find the derivative of the error function with respect each of the the parameters $w_i$
$$
r_1 = \frac{dE}{dw_1} = \frac{1}{m}\sum^m_j{2[y_j-w_1x_j+w_2]w_1}
$$
And 
$$
r_2 = \frac{dE}{dw_2} =  \frac{1}{m}\sum^m_j{2[y_j-w_1x_j+w_2]}
$$
Recall from before that knowing $r_i$ is a measure of how much the error changes with respect to each parameter. Therefore, we can apply our learning rule from before 
$$
w_{i,t+1}=w_{i,t}-\alpha \frac{dE}{dw_i}
$$

If you imagine that each parameter to ch  in the format $w_{i, t}$ then this statement tells us how to iterative  these definitions for $r_1$ and $r_2$ we can continue to update each $w$, assuming we have defined $\alpha$.  Usually a smaller learning rate is better.

We run the update rule rule a certain number of iterations:

From **theorem 1.1** we know the error is guaranteed to reach a minimum, where $w_{i,t}$ is the error at iteration $t$. The values of $w_1$ and $w_2$ at the end of our iterations will result in our model $f$ having been fit the the datapoints from the function $F$.

I hope this was a good introduction to the theory of numerical optimization. From here, we can start talking about more advanced theory, but this is the starting point.

### Exercises

1. What symbolic form would you use to fit a model with data looking like:
2. How about for

   **Hint:** use desmos.com to graph the function $f(x) = Ce^x + b$
3. Derive an equation for $r$ given a model with the format $f(x, w) = wx$ with the derivative rule $\frac{dD}{dw} = (y-wx)w$
4. **Implement this model in python.**

   1. Generate a dataset with the function $f(x) = w$ for some $w$ you choose
   2. Implement learning with your answer to question $3$ in python
   3. Run the algorithm four times for $\alpha = 0.025, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0$ for a number of iterations $n = 1000/\alpha$
   4. For each of the four times you run the algirithm, plot the values of $w$ and $E$.
   5. Compare your plots for each time you run the algorithm.
   6. Write up a little report summarizing your results and your thoughts as to why they are what they are.

### Exercises

1. What symbolic form would you use to fit a model with data looking like:  [image]
2. How about for
     [image]

   **Hint:** use desmos.com to graph the function $f(x) = Ce^x + b$
3. Derive an equation for $r$ given a model with the format $f(x, w) = wx$ with the derivative rule $\frac{dD}{dw} = (y-wx)w$
4. **Implement this model in python.**

   1. Generate a dataset with the function $f(x) = w$ for some $w$ you choose
   2. Implement learning with your answer to question $3$ in python
   3. Run the algorithm four times for $\alpha = 0.025, 0.2, 0.6, 1.0$ for a number of iterations $n = 1000/\alpha$
   4. For each of the four times you run the algirithm, plot the values of $w$ and $E$.
   5. Compare your plots for each time you run the algorithm.
   6. Write up a little report summarizing your results and your thoughts as to why they are what they are.

> In your case, you'd need to derive your equations for a polynomial of degree two, with two roots, i.e. $f(x,w_1, w_2, w_3)=w_1x^2+w_2x+w_3$
>
> Practically, you can write the code yourself or use microsoft excel to perform a quadratic fit on your data.
>
> If you think about it, this method can also be used to find the roots of any function no matter how complex it is, numerically. 
>   Lastly, these ideas form the basis of machine learning.